# Enum and RadioButtons

Tags: c#, winforms, enums

How can I tell if a radio button is checked and do something in switch? This is part of my code:

This is in my class Person.cs

```
 public enum TypeTimer { Unlimited, Countdown, Limited}
```

This is my switch where I will put the functions

```
public Person(TypeTimer s1)
        {
            switch (s1)
        {
            case TypeTimer.Unlimited:
                (code here)
                break;

            case TypeTimer.Countdown:
                     (code here)
                     break;
            case TypeTimer.Limited:
                    (code here)
                    break;
            default:
                    break;
        }
        }
```

How do I tell if checked == true is equal to enum limited or unlimited or countdown?

This is in Form.cs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbtnNormalTimer.Checked == true)
            {

            }
            else if(rbtnCountDown.Checked == true)
            {

            }
            else if(rbtnLimited.Checked == true)
            {

            }
        }
```

For example: If rbtnLimited is checked I want to execute the code that is inside the switch in TypeTimer.Limited
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You have everything in place. Just send in the corresponding enum value in each case to your class constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call the person method/constructor using the appropriate enum as following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbtnNormalTimer.Checked == true)
    {
        Person(TypeTimer.Unlimited);
    }
    else if(rbtnCountDown.Checked == true)
    {
        Person(TypeTimer.Countdown);
    }
    else if(rbtnLimited.Checked == true)
    {
        Person(TypeTimer.Limited);
    }
}
```

In the case of a constructor use it as follows:

```
Person person;
if (rbtnNormalTimer.Checked == true)
{
    person = new Person(TypeTimer.Unlimited);
}
else if(rbtnCountDown.Checked == true)
{
    person = new Person(TypeTimer.Countdown);
}
else if(rbtnLimited.Checked == true)
{
    person = new Person(TypeTimer.Limited);
}
```

Comment: Person is not a function!!

Comment: How are you calling the constructor?

Comment: @dotNET forgot the new keyword... things mess up if you try to be quick about it

Comment: Error: Person is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' and ´TypeTimer does not exist in the current context, is this what i am getting with your code

Comment: @MárioCorreia try again, I forgot the `new` keyword, and for the `TypeTimer` you should add a using to your own enum namespace then

Comment: still get ´TypeTimer does not exist in the current context

Comment: `TypeTimer` is the enum you defined. So you should use the enum by it's full namespace like: `My.Project.Namespace.TypeTimer` or add a using at the top of the document: `using My.Project.Namespace;`

Comment: Or maybe you have changed the name of the enum type and that is why it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: like this? :s `person = new Person(Person.TypeTimer.Unlimited);` becasue with this i don't have any error atm

Comment: Yes indeed, if TypeTimer is a subclass / subenum of Person then yes

Answer (score 0):

Hope that `public Person(TypeTimer s1)` will be the constructor of the `Person` class, and you want to create a new person object based on the radio button's selection the the following code will help you to complete the work; if it is not then you can call the method directly like`Person(TypeTimer.Unlimited)` this time don't forget add a valid return type in the method signature :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Person p;
     if (rbtnNormalTimer.Checked)
     {
       p= new Person(TypeTimer.Unlimited)
     }
     else if (rbtnCountDown.Checked)
     {
        p= new Person(TypeTimer.Countdown)
     }
     else if (rbtnLimited.Checked)
     {
        p= new Person(TypeTimer.Limited)
     }
  // proceed with p
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I make it normally with tag property of a control. After a control was checked I get its tag property and make smth like

```
TypeTimer enu;
Enum.TryParse((sender as RadioButton).Tag, out enu);
Switch(enu)
        {
            case TypeTimer.Unlimited:
                (code here)
                break;

            case TypeTimer.Countdown:
                     (code here)
                     break;
            case TypeTimer.Limited:
                    (code here)
                    break;
            default:
                    break;
        }
```